return 301 with nginx 1.24 is not working
I am trying to redirect http://foo.example.com to https://example.com:1234 [not really the port I am using ;-) ]
This used to work perfectly on an nginx 1.25 installation, but is not working on 1.24 on a different machine
Here's the relevant server block (this is in its own virtual host):
server {
# listen for regular (i.e. non-secure) http traffic
listen 80;

# Make site accessible from http://foo.example.com:1234
server_name foo.example.com;

# Redirect so all traffic goes through secure route and specified port
return 301 https://example.com:1234;
}

The "default" server virtual host .conf server block looks like this:
server {
# listen for regular (i.e. non-secure) http traffic
listen 80   default_server;

# Make site accessible from http://example.com:
server_name     example.com:;

# Redirect so all traffic goes through secure route
# use address from server_name variable
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

The default virtual host works fine, redirection does not.
BTW: this is on Fedora 39, where the deprecation of modular repos has made it much more difficult to install nginx 1.25
Any insights would be appreciated.  Thanks!

I'm 99% sure that your browser cached wrong redirect. Clear browser's cache.

Another way to bypass browser redirection cache is to use a privacy tab. Everyone testing redirection rules should use such tabs.

check the redirect with curl, it doesn't have any caching.
